# How to display MainWindow before the business logic execution has completed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, data-binding

So I am new to MVVM with WPF and am having trouble with a few concepts.
So as soon as you run, my MainViewModel will set up the model and will start pulling from the database in order to populate a list which is binded to one of my controls.

Now the problem is that, after it pulls data from the db it then needs to listen to another source which will fire an event and then add to this list. Now, this data source will fire events infinitely, so I would like to display the UI with the DB-pulled data and then update this list as events fire.

My initial idea was to only start this listen for updates once I have loaded and presented my control, but how is this done using the OnLoaded event in MVVM, I think this has been my biggest struggle.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1. Display a window. 2. Load the data. 3. Replace the contents of the window.

Comment: How do you load a window and then call a method using loaded event in wpf with mvvm. I know I can load a window and then update it, the problem is mvvm...

Comment: It is unclear what exactly your problem is. You may create and initialize the view model in a Loaded event handler of the MainWindow. The handler method may even be declared async in order to start and await any long running asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Hmm yes maybe its unclear. I think this is more so a problem with the fact that I dont know how mvvm works. When wpf create my ViewModel as it is one of the resources for binding, it will eventually start listening to incoming data. This listen will run infinitely, which mean the window ill never come up. I want an mvvm way to show the window with some data I already have and then have this listen work in the background

Comment: Why does "WPF create your view model"? You do that, but not in XAML, but in code behind, in the Loaded event handler. Set the view's DataContext after the view model is created. Or you split the creation and initialization of the view model. Add an Initialize method that does the long runnning things and call it in the Loaded handler.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Right now my ViewModel is a resource and the binding is done in design with xaml, i thought binding it in the MainWindow.cs class was bad in mvvm.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with Clemens' comment.

I now, bind the datasource in code and run the viewModel's listen method when the window is loaded, using the Loaded event. I am still not sure if this is a good MVVM solution so will probably change it again soon if it isn't.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).